# Not getting appledoc to document NS_ENUM

Tags: objective-c, enums, appledoc

could someone please explain what I am doing wrong when documenting my typedef NS_ENUM?

This is my syntax:

```
/** The different menu items
 */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, kMenuItem) {
    /** The start page */
    kMenuItemStartPage = 0,
    /** The new round item */
    kMenuItemNewRound,
    /** The archive item */
    kMenuItemArchive,
    /** The participants item */
    kMenuItemMyParticipants,
    /** The locations item */
    kMenuItemMyLocations,
    /** The settings */
    kMenuItemSettings,
    /** The contact page */
    kMenuItemContact,
    /** The count */
    kMenuItemTotal
};

/**
 * This is the Menu View Controller.
 *
 * The menu view controller handles the menu the menu and its options. You can access the menu view controller using the `menuContainer` in the `ApplicationDelegate`
 *
 */
@interface MenuTVC : UITableViewController


@end
```

My run script build phase:

```
APPLEDOC_PATH=`which appledoc`
if [ $APPLEDOC_PATH ]; then
echo "Generating docs!";
$APPLEDOC_PATH \
--project-name "${PRODUCT_NAME}" \
--project-company "Sogeti Sverige AB" \
--company-id "se.domain.project" \
--output "Docs" \
--no-install-docset \
--exit-threshold "2" \
--keep-undocumented-objects \
--keep-undocumented-members \
--keep-intermediate-files \
--ignore "Pods" \
--ignore ".m" \
--index-desc "${PROJECT_DIR}/Readme.md" \
${PROJECT_DIR}/Prevent
else
echo "AppleDoc not found or installed!"
fi;
```

The result:
[image: google chromescreensnapz007]

And build result: 
[image: xcodescreensnapz011]

From the terminal:

```
$ which appledoc
/usr/bin/appledoc
$ appledoc --version
appledoc version: 2.2 (build 963)
```

I just can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that the enums are documented in the `index.html` file, and not the class documentation itself.

It does work.

[image: Result page]

Comment: Yes, that's how Apple does it. Appledoc is designed to mimic Apple's documentation. Enums are not part of any class, so they aren't in your class definition docs.

Comment: Thats what I learned today =) I just didn't expect it there and whatever I tried, when I refreshed the "class" page, it didn't document it [there]... now I know why ;)

Answer (score 0):

Appledoc doesn't currently support enums. It's quite a, shall we say, popular feature request:

https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/2

Comment: It does support it, and I just figured out that its in the index.html, but expected it in the class documentation.

Comment: But enums are not really part of a class. They're just often declared in the same file.

Comment: Yeah, ideally they should be declared separately.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Things must have moved on since I last looked at this!

Comment: @PaulPeelen It probably supports them only as a list of constants?

Comment: @Sulthan did you read the above comments, or the answer on the question?